# Accidentally deleted .mypy_cache folder

Tags: python, django, mypy

While running python type checker for django project with invoke I get the error:

```
File "/Users/myusername/.pyenv/versions/3.8.3/lib/python3.8/genericpath.py", line 55, in getmtime
        return os.stat(filename).st_mtime
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.mypy_cache/3.8/django/core/exceptions.data.json'
```

I accidentally deleted .mypy_cache folder to troubleshoot another problem. So now I don't know where the .mypy_cache folder should live and is there any command to get it back again?

Edit:
Now, after running mypy, I have got the `exceptions.data.json` inside mypy_cache now, but it still keeps saying No file found.
It's on the same path as it's saying not found.
How can I make this exception file found?
Without this I'm not able to run type-checker

Comment: If you delete the whole `.mypy_cache` folder, that should be fine; mypy should create it next time it runs.

Answer (score 3):

it usually live in under the main project as a folder.

```
project
|-- .mypy_cache
|-- ...
```

well nothing too bad has happened, you can simply run `mypy` again and it will create a new cache folder.

what will happen is next time you run `mypy` it would take it a little longer since he has to go all over again.

Comment: I have edited my post with the latest update that still throws the same error.

Comment: delete `.mypy_cache`

run `mypy -p <name_of_your_package>`

if it doesn't work send your output and what you have tried